# UDP packet creation in goLang

Tags: go

I am trying to create a raw UDP packet. UDP packet consists of 3 parts:

1. MessageId
2. Payload
3. checksum

Message-ID is defined as:
The first 4 bytes are the client IP, the next 2 bytes are the port number, the next 2 bytes are randomly generated, and the last 8 bytes the time the request was generated (e.g., in nanoseconds). Alternatively, one could use UUIDs.
My questions is : Are there any libraries in Golang like which converts IP address into a byte array? If so, what I am assuming is that to create MessageID in my case, I need to have 4 bytes arrays corresponding to IP address, 2 bytes port number, 2 bytes random generated number, and 8 bytes long time stamp. Thereafter, I will merge all of them in one array to form 16 byte-long Message-ID. Please help me to know if my understanding is correct here or not?

I would highly appreciate the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any libraries in Golang like which converts IP address into a byte array?

The Go type for an IP address is [net.IP](https://pkg.go.dev/net#IP).  A net.IP is a slice of bytes.

Use the builtin [copy](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#copy) function to initialize a byte [array](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types) from a byte [slice](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types):

```
 var myArray [4]byte
 copy(myArray[:], myIPAddress)
```